# ValueError: Bytes length does not equal format and resolution size

Tags: python, pygame

So, I was creating some `pygame` program, and I wanted to embed a `.png` image with `pygame.image.fromstring` but I keep getting the error above. I have tried other things like `frombytes` and changing the size iterables but it won't work. The code I used to convert the image:

```py
import base64

with open("my_image.png", "rb") as imageFile:
    bytes = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())
    print(bytes)
```

And the image surface:

```py
imageBytes = b'imagedata'
image = pygame.image.fromstring(imageBytes, (width,height), "RGBA")
```

After I converted my image of choice, I simply copied the output and pasted it in `vs-code` and it returns the error message. How can I fix this? Help is appreciated!

Comment: Do not use `str` as a variable name. You should not use any python keyword as a variable name.

Comment: @rochard4u That isn't the problem though, just tested

Comment: No it is just common advice (`bytes` is also a keyword btw). From what I read from the [pygame documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.fromstring), `fromstring` expect a byte buffer. Why do you think it expects a byte string created from a b64 encoded string instead ?

Comment: PNG images are compressed and are not just a list of RGBA quadruplets. You need to decompress and parse the file first, like `pygame.image.load(...)` does. `fromstring` requires raw uncompressed data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pygame.image.fromstring(imageBytes...)` won't work because this function expects the string to be in a certain format.

To get a string that works with `fromstring` you have to load the image into a `Surface` and then use `pygame.image.tostring` (or the `tobytes`/`frombytes` counterparts).

You load your image and convert it into a base64 encoded string, so you could actually decode it back and load it with `pygame.image.load`, like this:

```
import io
image = pygame.image.load(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(imageBytes)))
```

Comment: This seems all over the place. Instead of telling OP to remove the weird encoding to b64, you tell them to decode the b64 and wrap it in BytesIO... Why not just remove what OP does wrong? then the code is simple `with open("my_image.png", "rb") as f: image = pygame.image.load(f)`.

Comment: @h4z3 I want to not include external files, hence why I said "embed" and that is why is doesn't help me